# Correct way to allocate memory for structure?

Tags: c

I am trying to determine the best way to allocate memory for a dynamic number of pixels read from a file. I have the number of bytes of pixel data from the header file.

I am trying it in the following way, but am missing something.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
} pixel_t; 

for(i = 0; i <= ((bmp->dib.bmp_bytesz) / 3); i++) {
    // Something here?
}
```

Comment: did you try `malloc(bmp->dib.bmp_bytesz)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the memory allocation probably doesn't go where you indicated:

```
pixel_t *pixels = malloc(((bmp->dib.bmp_bytesz/3)+1) * sizeof(*pixels));
if (pixels == 0)
    ...deal with out of memory error...

for (int i = 0; i <= bmp->dib.dmp_bytesz/3; i++)
{
    pixels[i].blue = ...;
    pixels[i].green = ...;
    pixels[i].red = ...;
}
```

The `+1` allows for the `<=` in the `for` loop.  Be careful to check that the `<=` is correct; it is more usual to use `<` in a `for` loop.

---

> For the `...`, what if I have the pixels in a `char` array? How can I step through it and copy into the pixels?

You can do it in either of a couple of ways.  Assuming the pixel array is in `unsigned char *pixel_array;`, then you could use:

```
unsigned char *p = pixel_array;

for (int i = 0; i <= bmp->dib.dmp_bytesz/3; i++)
{
    pixels[i].blue  = *p++;
    pixels[i].green = *p++;
    pixels[i].red   = *p++;
}
```

or:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= bmp->dib.dmp_bytesz/3; i++)
{
    pixels[i].blue  = pixel_array[i*3+0];
    pixels[i].green = pixel_array[i*3+1];
    pixels[i].red   = pixel_array[i*3+2];
}
```

Just make sure you get the blue, green, red sequence correct.

Comment: For the ..., what if I have the pixels in an char array? How can I step through it and copy into the pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Need to allocate memory for pixel before doing something in the for loop.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
} pixel_t; 
pixel_t *pixel = (pixel_t *)malloc(bmp->dib.bmp_bytesz);
if(pixel == NULL) { exit(-1); }

for(i = 0; i < ((bmp->dib.bmp_bytesz) / 3); i++) {
    // Something here?
    pixel[i].blue = bmp->dib[3 * i];
    pixel[i].green = bmp->dib[3 * i + 1];
    pixel[i].red = bmp->dib[3 * i + 2];
}
```

Comment: Very similar to mine...but I have to quibble; if `bmp->dib.bmp_bytesz` is valid, `bmp->dib[3*i]` probably isn't correct (it would need to be `bmp->dib.pixel_array[3*i+0]` or `bmp->pixel_array[3*i+0]` or something similar.  Details in the structure type that `bmp` points to that is not given in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, just an example for the operations in the for loop.